# why i am getting this error ? "Query was already executed: Product.find({ price: { '$lte': 1000, '$gte': 1 } })"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, axios

I am fetching API request from my frontend as I am using reactjs
When I try to filter product by price I am getting unexpected error:

**axios call**

```
axios.get(`/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&price[gte]=${price[0]}`)
```

**Backend**
In my backend i am handling the get request as

```
exports.getProducts =  (req, res, next) => {
  const resPerPage = 4;
  const productsCount = await Product.countDocuments();

  const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Product.find(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter();

  let products = await apiFeatures.query;
  let filteredProductsCount = products.length;

  apiFeatures.pagination(resPerPage);
  products = await apiFeatures.query;

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    productsCount,
    resPerPage,
    filteredProductsCount,
    products,
  });
};
```

and my APIFeatures.js is

```
class APIFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryStr) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryStr = queryStr;
  }
  search() {
    const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword
      ? {
          name: {
            $regex: this.queryStr.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        }
      : {};
    this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
    return this;
  }
  filter() {
    const queryCopy = { ...this.queryStr };

    // removing fields from the query
    const removeFields = ['keyword', 'limit', 'page'];
    removeFields.forEach((el) => delete queryCopy[el]);

    //   advance filter for price, ratings etc
    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryCopy);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);

    this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
    return this;
  }
  pagination(resPerPage) {
    const currentPage = Number(this.queryStr.page) || 1;
    const skip = resPerPage * (currentPage - 1);
    this.query = this.query.limit(resPerPage).skip(skip);
    return this;
  }
}
module.exports = APIFeatures;
```

But when i dispatch get request from my frontend i am getting error about my price filter

**Error**

```
"Query was already executed: Product.find({ price: { '$lte': 1000, '$gte': 1 } })"
```

Answer (score 4):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution

```
products = await apiFeatures.query.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

hey I was facing the same issue
a quick fix for this is to use clone when you are executing the query again.

like this:-

```
products = await apiFeature.query.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Product.find().exec(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter();
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!

Comment: this is also not working. I had already try that

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
let products = await apiFeatures.query.clone();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose throws a 'Query was already executed' error when a given query is executed twice. The most common explanation for this is you're mixing await and callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a dummy instance of class Apifeature and dont use pagination on it and find filteredProductsCount and then create another instance of class Apifeature and use pagination on it. This worked for me.

```
exports.getAllProducts = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
const resultperpage = 8;
const productcount = await Product.countDocuments();
const apifeaturesdemo = new ApiFeatures(Product.find(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter();
let products = aenter code herewait apifeaturesdemo.query;
let filteredProductsCount = products.length;
// apifeatures.pagination(resultperpage);
const apifeatures = new ApiFeatures(Product.find(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter()
    .pagination(resultperpage);
products = await apifeatures.query;
if (!products) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Product not found", 404));
}
res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    products,
    productcount,
    resultperpage,
    filteredProductsCount,
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing this problem.
so write the below code to solve this problem.

products = await apiFeatures.query.clone();

Comment: Hi, this is identical to the previous answer. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34347034)